# Merge counter.items() dictionaries into one dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, merge, counter

How do I get the output of this code into one dictionary with total number of key:value pairs?

```
import re
from collections import Counter

splitfirst = open('output.txt', 'r')
input = splitfirst.read()
output = re.split('\n', input)

for line in output:
    counter = Counter(line)
    ab = counter.items() #gives list of tuples will be converted to dict
    abdict = dict(ab)
    print abdict
```

Here is a sample of what I get:

```
{' ': 393, '-': 5, ',': 1, '.': 1}
{' ': 382, '-': 4, ',': 5, '/': 1, '.': 5, '|': 1, '_': 1, '~': 1}
{' ': 394, '-': 1, ',': 2, '.': 3}
{'!': 1, ' ': 386, 'c': 1, '-': 1, ',': 3, '.': 3, 'v': 1, '=': 1, '\\': 1, '_': 1, '~': 1}
{'!': 3, ' ': 379, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'g': 1, ')': 1, 'j': 1, '-': 3, ',': 2, '.': 1, 't': 1, 'z': 2, ']': 1, '\\': 1, '_': 2}
```

I have 400 of such dictionaries, and Ideally I have to merge them together, but if I understand correctly Counter does not give them all, rather gives them all one after another.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

data = """this is the first line
this is the second one
this is the last one
"""

output = Counter()
for line in re.split('\n', data):
    output += Counter(line)

print output
```

Applying the method in your example you'd get this:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

    output = Counter()
    for line in re.split('\n', data):
        output += Counter(line)

    print output
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator merges counters:

```
>>> Counter('hello') + Counter('world')
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'e': 1, 'r': 1, 'h': 1, 'd': 1, 'w': 1})
```

so you can use `sum` to combine a collection of them:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = list(f)

counters = [Counter(line) for line in lines]
combined = sum(counters, Counter())
```

(You also don’t need to use regular expressions to split files into lines; they’re already iterables of lines.)

Comment: I get error: combined = sum(counters)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'

Comment: @KristianVybiral: I forgot the initial value, sorry! It'd be `sum(counters, Counter())`.

Comment: Thank you many times! This is perfect! I'm not sure how this really works, as I was thinking completely differently.